# Is it possible to receive Luck Up collecting a coin?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac-rebirth, the-binding-of-isaac-afterbirth

I'm doing the Daily run (today is with The Lost) and something strange has just happened.
I've collected a normal Coin and the message "*Luck Up*" has popped up.

How is this possible? Is there now a chance of *Luck Up* collecting coins?

---

Here are my current items, I don't think this is related to them:

- Dad's Key
- Synthoil
- Virgo
- Dead Cat

[image]

Comment: I dont have the DLC, but it might have to do with the daily challenge. Just a guess.

Comment: @ShadowZ. it could be

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When donating for the first time to the Greed Machine after beating Ultra Greed, you unlock the Lucky Pennies achievement. This achievement grants a small chance of replacing the normal pennies with a version that gives Luck Up when you pick them up, that's what's giving you the effect.

Comment: You are right, but you unlock that penny donating the first penny to the *Greed Donation Machine*, IIRC. Anyway, I can say that the Lucky Penny is a different pickup itself, because if you have *Humbling Bundle* every normal penny has the "1+1 free" version, except the lucky one that appears alone.

Comment: @pinckerman thanks for the info, I've updated my answer

Comment: Perfect, now I can accept it :)

Answer (score 5):

Jeah, they seemed to have added a chance for a luck up from picking up pennies. Might be related to some kind of "lucky penny". Had that effect a few times now in different runs with different items and different characters, so I am pretty sure that it is not related to any item.

Comment: That's nice! I'll wait for other answers before accepting yours.